# Using XPathAll in Pig when Parent Node has Namespace

Tags: xml, xpath, apache-pig

I am trying to run an XML file through a Pig script on Azure. I have been running into problems, that I think may be due to my parent node having a namespace.

```
REGISTER 'piggybank-0.15.0.jar';
DEFINE XPathAll org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.xml.XPathAll();
A = LOAD 'file.xml' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('Parent') as (x:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE XPathAll(x, 'Parent/Child', true, true);
DUMP B;
```

The script runs without errors, but returns an empty result: (). Do I have to call XMLLoader differently because of the namespace?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you need to declare a prefix, say `ns`, referencing the default namespace URI, and then use that prefix to reference element in the default namespace :

```
ns:Parent/ns:Child
```

I don't use Pig so don't know whether it support prefix declaration. Pure XPath approach would be matching element by combination of *local-name* and *namespace-uri* (wrapped for readability) :

```
*[local-name()='Parent' and namespace-uri()='default ns URI here']
/*[local-name()='Child' and namespace-uri()='default ns URI here']
```

If there is no other element with the same name in other namespace, then you can simplify the XPath by stripping off `namespace-uri` criteria :

```
*[local-name()='Parent']/*[local-name()='Child']
```